# method that returns the employees that has three 'a' on the surname

Tags: c#, arrays

I just want to know how i can check in array for an element with two "a" in them and return them

i tried this:

```
public string CheckTwoNames()
{
    string name = salesmen[0].GetFirstName();
    int num=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (salesmen[i].GetFirstName().Contains("a"))
        {
            if (num>=2)
            {
                num++;
                name = salesmen[i].GetFirstName();
                
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Exactly two "a", or at least two "a"? English language can be ambiguous...

Comment: Compare the title of the question with the body

Comment: Hmm, comparing the title of the question with its body, i get minus one.

Comment: Title is three, question is two. Which one is it?

Comment: The title also asks about surname while the code shows about first name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to check if a string contains n letters:

```
public static bool ContainsLetters(string input, char letter, int count, bool exactCount)
{
    return exactCount
        ? input.Count(c => c == letter) == count 
        : input.Count(c => c == letter) >= count;
}
```

so you could use it for example here:

```
string salesManFirstName = salesmen[i].GetFirstName();
if (ContainsLetters(salesManFirstName, 'a', 2, false))
{
    return salesManFirstName;
}
```

or your whole method as a single LINQ query:

```
return salesmen.FirstOrDefault(s => ContainsLetters(s.GetFirstName(), 'a', 2, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement will return all employees having two "a" characters in their first name.

```
Salesmen.Where(e => e.GetFirstName().Count(c => (c == 'a')) == 2).ToList();
```